# Java: Storing properties in an object

Tags: java, arrays, constants

I have a class like the following:

```
public class Prefs {
    public static final int PREF_NAME = 0;
    public static final int PREF_SURNAME = 1;
    public static final int PREF_LOCATION = 2;

    String[] defaults = { "unknown", "unknown", "nowhere" }
    String[] prefs;

    public String getPref(int id) {
        return prefs[id];
    }
}
```

So I can use the following syntax:

```
Prefs p = new Prefs();
p.setDefaults() // irrelevant code not included
p.getPref(Prefs.PREF_LOCATION); // much more readable than getPref(2);
```

Is this approach correct? Are there any better options to do accomplish this?

EDIT: Please provide a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

I think `enum` would be exactly what you need and perfect.

Comment: I also have a `setPref(id, val)` method, so I think I cannot use enums. I've never used them, but I thought it were only constants.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of elements in 'prefs' is going to be dynamic, you may want to consider using a hashtable: -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

This would allow you to have a key that would refer to the specific element.

> (From the javadoc) This example creates a hashtable of numbers. It uses the names of the numbers as keys:

```
 Hashtable numbers = new Hashtable();
 numbers.put("one", new Integer(1));
 numbers.put("two", new Integer(2));
 numbers.put("three", new Integer(3));
```

To retrieve a number, use the following code:

```
 Integer n = (Integer)numbers.get("two");
 if (n != null) {
     System.out.println("two = " + n);
 }
```

Alternatively, you can use an ArrayList if you want random access.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

Either use `enum` or `ValuedEnum` (org.appache.commons), when values do not change.
In ValuedEnum you can provide custom texts, for a value, the standard enum uses the enum field name as text.

if you are using the java enum, consider using the approach where you explicitly assign a value to the enum (by providing an enum constrcutor with paramater "value").

From [javarevisited](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.at/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html) :

```
public enum Currency {
         PENNY(1), NICKLE(5), DIME(10), QUARTER(25);
         private int value;

        private Currency(int value) {
                this.value = value;
        } 

};
```

This Valied enum approach is neccessary when you want to make sure that the values never changes (e.g for persitence). java ordinal() can not provide that.